# emptying some `li` from listview using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile

I have a working listview populated by js.  I wanted to add an option to hide the listview but retain the listdivider.  I can only come up with this:

```
$('#myList').empty()
```

and this emmpties everyrthing.  How can I empty the list but not the listdivider?

many thanks.

Comment: what do you understand by listdivider ? give us some html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML I'm assuming here, but try this:

```
$('#myList li').not("#divider").remove()
```

This will remove each `li` element contained in `#myList`, except the `li` with an id of `divider`.

You will need to put whatever valid selector will catch your dividing element in the `not()` method.

Comment: It seems jQuery Mobile uses `data-role='list-divider'`, so this should do it: `$("#myList li").not("[data-role='list-divider']").remove()`.